# Downloading climate data?

Tags: data, download, climate

I just want somebody to help me with a link so that I can download global climatic data variables like temperature, precipitation, cloud cover etc

Comment: http://www.worldclim.org/ and http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/getData

Answer (score 2):

For temperature and precipitation,  you can use the [Worldclim](http://www.worldclim.org/) dataset, but it does not include cloud cover.

Comment: If its useful, GeoTiffs of cloud fraction, cirrus reflectance and cloud optical thickness can be found here: http://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/about/ftp.php

Comment: I will check the site right away

Comment: I have visited the worldclim website but it seems may be i dont know how to arrange the data according to the number of years I want. I need the data from 1980 to 2012 but there is no space to add the year one needs do download. Can somebody direct me on how to download it from 1982 to 2012 in tif format

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what, where and when in longtime terms you need.

Historical datasets:

http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/ghcnm/

http://www.gewex.org/gpcp.html

In Europe since 2000  http://www.ogimet.com/index.phtml.en but you need a metar parser.

In Europe more close to climate models you can use 
http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/ from ERA-Interim program.

In Germany CDC Climate Data center sometimes hourly back to 1947
ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/